# Serialize data to json string with dynamic property names

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a method which accepts a key and a value. Both variables can have a dynamic content.

key => is a dynamic string which can be everything like e.g. "LastSentDate"
value => is an object which can be everything like e.g. "2014-10-10"

As key is a dynamic value like "LastSentDate" or whatever key is passed to the method then I want           that the json property is the value of the key string and not literally key itself...

```
public void SetRowVariable(string key, object value)
{
    var obj = new { key = value }; // key property is literally taken maybe anonym object is not a good idea?
     string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    // jsonString should have that output => "{ "LastSentDate": "2014-10-10" }"
}
```

How do I have to serialize the obj that I get the wished output?

It must also be possible that the "key" property can contain special chars like "!"§$%&/()=?"`

I am using .NET 3.5 sadly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a `JObject` (in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq):

```
var obj = new JObject();
obj[key] = JToken.FromObject(value);

string jsonString = obj.ToString();
```

Comment: After trying out some things like AddOrUpdate behavior of a JObject I must say your tip is really good it totally fitted into what I tried:

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: Your solution is also a great approach to serialize an object with the root element included: `obj[ value.GetType().Name ] = JToken.FromObject( value );`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker : Even after 8 years of your answer, you saved the day for me :)

Answer (score 11):

You may try using a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
public void SetRowVariable(string key, object value)
{
    var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    obj[key] = value; // Of course you can put whatever crap you want here as long as your keys are unique
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whose answer is better or wether I really need the overhead of a dictionary vs solution from @Andrew Whitaker, first I  have to do another SO question... :-)

Comment: Darin you rock in MVC ;-) but this point goes to Andrew. But hey you got 4 upvotes :P