# ASP.NET MVC. Create model to convert into JSON-object (with dynamic name property)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I need to generate Json-output like this:

```
{
    "01:30":{
        "FREE":true,
        "PRICE":3500
     },
    "03:00":{
        "FREE":true,
        "PRICE":2500
    },
    "13:30":{
        "FREE":true,
        "PRICE":2500
    }
}
```

My problem here is time string - its dynamic from one entry to another. I can not figure out how to construct my c# class (model) that will be serialized into proper json result.
My model looks like this now:

```
public class ScheduleViewModel
{
    public ScheduleInnerViewModel TIME { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleInnerViewModel
{
    public bool FREE { get; set; }
    public int PRICE { get; set; }
}
```

Output result is (wrong):

```
[
    {"TIME":{
        "FREE":true,
        "PRICE":3500
     }},
    {"TIME":{
        "FREE":true,
        "PRICE":2500
    }},
    {"TIME":{
        "FREE":true,
        "PRICE":2500
    }}
]
```

I use standard way to generate json result from controller:

```
List<ScheduleViewModel> model = new List<ScheduleViewModel>();
//fill the model...
return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: "01:30" you need a variable to represent this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about having a dictionary where the key is a string (your timestamp) and the data is your model class ?

Like:

```
Dictionary<string, ScheduleInnerViewModel> dic = new Dictionary<string, ScheduleInnerViewModel>();

dic.Add("01:30", new ScheduleInnerViewModel{ Free = false, Price = 100 });
dic.Add("04:25", new ScheduleInnerViewModel{ Free = false, Price = 200 });
dic.Add("13:00", new ScheduleInnerViewModel{ Free = true, Price = 0 });

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dic, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented });

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try the unaccepted answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874014/serialize-data-to-json-string-with-dynamic-property-names). It uses a Dictionary to create the property name (key) and then you can use your ScheduleInnerViewModel as the value so something like:

```
 var obj = new Dictionary<string, ScheduleInnerViewModel>();
```

Comment: seems I came a minute late :)